Ubuntu Account Lock Message
How to change the display message from "The account is locked due to 3 failed logins.(10 minutes left to unlock)" to “Login incorrect”

Why would you do that? It makes it harder to explain login failures to $USER. Do you want $USER to keep retrying, even though attempts 4 through infinity are foredoomed to failure? That seems unkind.
